# Is this a merge between a branch and master?

Tags: git, merge, branch, merge-conflict-resolution

Hey there I am new to git and need help to solve a serious problem. I wanted to push a branch what was getting a message, that is out of sync with the repository and therefore I pulled it. I do not remember which steps I took exactly, but now I am seeing this on my git bash:

[image]

Does this mean that I am about to merge my master with the branch *added_components*. If so how can I undo that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "(added_components|MERGING)" mention at the end of your prompt tells you that you're currently in the process of merging something into the branch. Then "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged" tells us that the branch being merged into `added_components` is `master`. This answers part of your question : **Yes, this is a merge between your branch and master.**

I think we can safely assume you used `git pull origin master` with your branch `added_components` checked out.

Since there's no mention of conflicting files, to complete the merge you'd just have to commit to finish the process.

If, in the other hand, you do *not* want to proceed with the merge, just abort it with

```
git merge --abort
```

and your branch will be restored in the state it was just before the merge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So this does not mean that I am merging the master with the branch, just that I adapted some changes possibly when pulling to the current branch and that I need to commit these changes by merging?

Comment: I edited my answer, I had misread in the first place and assumed a merge with the remote counterpart of `added_components`

Answer (score 1):

At that point seems like you are in the middle of a merge that had conflicts and you have solved them all. You need to finish the merge operation for the revision to be created: `git commit --no-edit`. That will use the same comment that you provided when you ran the `git merge` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you tell what kind of merging this is? Is it a merge between my branch and master or between an old and an new version of the branch?